# Dynamically break down table td into individual tr's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that I am trying to make mobile friendly see below:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>one</td>
  <td>one</td>
  <td>one</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td>two</td>
  <td>two</td>
  <td>two</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
```

I'm looking to create single columns of this table so it can be display better on mobile.
Conceptually I'm thinking to ad an /tr after each /td excluding /td:last of types

My tables are dynamically generated, so it needs to dynamic solution, anyone have anythoughts on how to approach this?

Below is what the resulting table would ideally look like.

```
<tbody>
<tr><td>one</td></tr>
<tr><td>one</td></tr>
<tr><td>one</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr><td>two</td></tr>
<tr><td>two</td></tr>
<tr><td>two</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How about you show us what you tried first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve the same look with CSS and media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) { /* or whatever you want your mobile breakpoint to be */
    tr, td { float:left; width:100%; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nWPzp/

Comment: Very clean and doesn't require any JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not displaying tabular data I find my preference is to stay away from tables and use lists/divs instead.  That being said here are some examples of "Responsive Tables" that do contain tabular data:

http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

As pointed out a lot of them are css tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Try JS. Use getElementById. Write:
    
    document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML="new code"